# How to read back a column name with spaces using linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, select

I'm reading back a query using a linq Select where some of the SQL Server database column names include blank spaces in the column name.

Reading back the first column `ID` works fine and I can see the query being returned. But when I add in the second column with spaces taken from the DB schema, `[Contact Email Name]` it throws an `invalid column name exception`:

[image]

I did try as suggested here adding the `DataMemberAttribute` to the property name, but the same exception is thrown:

```
public class Status
{

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Contact Email Name")]
    public string Contact_Email_Name { get; set; }


}
```

**Question:**

How can you read back a column name with spaces using linq?

This is the linq statement where the column values are read back:

```
            var query_all = from n in db3.Statuses
                            select new
                            {
                                ID = n.ID,
                                Contact_Email_Name = n.Contact_Email_Name,

                            };
```

Comment: Try the `ColumnAttribute` instead of `DataMemberAttribute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `Column` attribute instead of `DataMember`

```
public class Status
{

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column("Contact Email Name")]
    public string Contact_Email_Name { get; set; }


}
```